# Microsoft Cognitive Services Video API call for face detection

Tags: video, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to test the Microsoft Cognitive Video API for face detection, whenever i try the code samples in java, I get access denied error due to subscription key not valid. Though this works in the microsoft provided open testing console. Could someone tell me whether the sample code is correct or something is missing. Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to update the sample code with your subscription key? Also make sure:

- There are no leading or trailing spaces
- All characters in the key are lowercase

If neither of these work, can you link me to the exact sample you're using?